# Error 5 getting directory when i take photo in Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova

I am getting photos, and i want to show them (it works) and save them on my directory. I followed mixed responses from this forum and w3c to obtain this code. My problem is when im getting the fileSys directory, it goes to onError, it cant get myFolderApp directory. Monitor shows "

> Failed to ensure directory:
>   /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/tta.kirolapp.v1/files

and

> Failed to ensure directory:
>   /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/tta.kirolapp.v1/files

This is normal because the app default directory is

> /storage/emulated/0/0Android/data/tta.kirolapp.v1/

so, i think this is the problem but i don't know how to fix it.
The code of the functions which takes the photo and manage it, is the next:

```
function capturePhoto() {
    alert('on capturePhoto');

    sessionStorage.removeItem('imagepath');
    //Cogemos la imagen y la codificamos en Base64
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, cameraDirection: 1, saveToPhotoAlbum:true, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) { 
        // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
        // console.log(imageData);

        // Get image handle
        //
        var imgProfile = document.getElementById('fotoRegistro');

        // Pasamos la imagen a pantalla desde imageURI
        //
        console.log('El url por defecto es: '+ imageURI);
        imgProfile.src = imageURI;
        if(sessionStorage.isprofileimage==1){
            getLocation();
        }
        movePic(imageURI);
}

// Funcion onError
// 
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function movePic(file){ 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError); 
} 

//Callback function when the file system uri has been resolved
function resolveOnSuccess(entry){ 
    console.log("Estoy en resolveOnSuccess");
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    //new file name
    var identificacion= $('#idEmailReg').val();
    var newFileName="foto"+identificacion+".jpg";
    console.log ('El newFileName es: '+ newFileName);
    var myFolderApp = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/tta.kirolapp.v1/img/";
        //appConstants.localPermanentStorageFolderImg;
    console.log ('El nuevo directorio es: '+ myFolderApp);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {      
    console.log ('Entramos en el request onSuccess');
    //The folder is created if doesn't exist
    fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                    {create:true, exclusive: false},
                    function(directory) {
                        console.log('El directory es: '+ directory);
                        entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  successMove, resOnError);
                    },
                    resOnError);
                    },
    resOnError);
}

//Callback function when the file has been moved successfully - inserting the complete path
function successMove(entry) {
    //Store imagepath in session for future use
    // like to store it in database

    sessionStorage.setItem('imagepath', entry.fullPath);
}

function resOnError(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}
```

resOnError shows code "5", and the monitor output is the next:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the media plugin and take the photos with photo capturing, this is the code:

```
function capturePhoto(){
    //var fileFolder="/storage/emulated/0/KirolApp/img/";
    var fileFolder=appConstants.localPermanentStorageFolderImg();
    var identificacion= $('#idEmailReg').val();
    var fileName="foto"+identificacion+".jpg";  
    photo.takeAsync(
        fileFolder,
        fileName,
        function() {
            console.log('En capturePhoto funcion');
            var urlCompleta=photo.fileFolder+photo.fileName;
            console.log('URL Completa: '+ urlCompleta);

            $("#fotoRegistro").attr("src","file://"+urlCompleta+"?"+(new Date()).getTime());
        }
    );
}
```

On my objects.js file:

```
var photo = {
        fileFolder:null,
        fileName:null,
        takeAsync: function(fileFolder,fileName,onSuccess) {
            navigator.device.capture.captureImage(
                function(photoFiles) {
                    var tempFullPath=photoFiles[0].fullPath;
                    tempFullPath=tempFullPath.substring(tempFullPath.indexOf("/"));

                    alert("New photo in: "+tempFullPath);

                    fileUtilities.moveAsync(tempFullPath,fileFolder,fileName,
                        function() {
                            photo.fileFolder=fileFolder;
                            photo.fileName=fileName;
                            if(onSuccess!=false)
                                onSuccess();
                        }                           
                    );
                },
                function(error) {
                    var msgText = "Photo error: " + error.message + "(" + error.code + ")";
                    alert(msgText);
                }
            );
        }
};
```

And fileUtilities:

```
var fileUtilities = {
        moveAsync: function (sourceFullPath,destFolder,destName,onSuccess){
            var url="file://"+sourceFullPath;
            var destFile=destFolder+destName;
            var ft=new FileTransfer();
            ft.download(url,destFile,
                function() {
                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(url,
                            function(fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.remove(onSuccess);
                            },
                            function(error) {
                                alert("Source file NOT accesible; not removed");
                            }
                    );          
                },
                function(error) {
                    alert('File not copied. '+'error.code: '+error.code+'\nerror.source: '+error.source+'\nerror.target: '+error.target+'\nerror.http_status: '+error.http_status);
                }
            );
        }
};
```

Thanks to M.H and G.P from UPV/EHU.